# Possible bug in Series.interpolate

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to align my index values between multiple `DataFrame`s or Series and I'm using 
Series.interpolate but it doesn't seem to interpolate correctly.  Or perhaps I am misunderstanding something. Here's a small example:

```
x1 = np.array([0, 0.25, 0.77, 1.2, 1.4, 2.6, 3.1])
y1 = np.array([0, 1.1, 0.5, 1.5, 1.2, 2.1, 2.4])
x2 = np.array([0, 0.25, 0.66, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 3.1])
y2 = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.8, 1.1, 2.2, 0.1, 2.4])

df1 = DataFrame(data=y1, index=x1, columns=['A'])
df1.plot(marker='o')

df2 = DataFrame(data=y2, index=x2, columns=['A'])
df2.plot(marker='o')

df3=df1 - df2
df3.plot(marker='o')
print df3

def resample(signals):
    aligned_x_vals = reduce(lambda s1, s2: s1.index.union(s2.index), signals)
    return map(lambda s: s.reindex(aligned_x_vals).apply(Series.interpolate), signals)

sig1, sig2 = resample([df1, df2])
sig3 = sig1 - sig2
plt.plot(df1.index, df1.values, marker='D')
plt.plot(sig1.index, sig1.values, marker='o')
plt.grid()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df2.index, df2.values, marker='o')
plt.plot(sig2.index ,sig2.values, marker='o')
plt.grid()
```

I expect sig1 and sig2 to have more points than df1 and df2 but with the values interpolated.  There are a few points that are not overlapping.  Is this a bug or user error?  I'm using v0.7.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *might* be a bug. Looking at the source, `Series.interpolate` doesn't look at the index values while doing interpolation. It assumes they are equally spaced and just uses `len(serie)` for indexes. Maybe this is the intention and it's not a bug. I'm not sure.

I modified the `Series.interpolate` method and came up with this `interpolate` function. This will do what you want.

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *

def interpolate(serie):
    try:
        inds = np.array([float(d) for d in serie.index])
    except ValueError:
        inds = np.arange(len(serie))

    values = serie.values

    invalid = isnull(values)
    valid = -invalid

    firstIndex = valid.argmax()
    valid = valid[firstIndex:]
    invalid = invalid[firstIndex:]
    inds = inds[firstIndex:]

    result = values.copy()
    result[firstIndex:][invalid] = np.interp(inds[invalid], inds[valid],
                                             values[firstIndex:][valid])

    return Series(result, index=serie.index, name=serie.name)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll have to get used to looking at the source from now on.  Do you think I should open a bug in the issue tracker.  IMHO if the index is of type float then it should not make this assumption.

Comment: @Slothman: Bug report is a good idea. I would expect the same behavior like you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think underlying mathematics apply that sum of interpolation equal to interpolation of sum. it only holds at special case